# How to transfer all my files to another user, including permissions

Tags: permissions, users

I have to create another user and transfer all my files to "him". The problem on Linux is that the new user will not be able to access them/edit them. Is there a fast command to transfer all files AND change all their permissions?

Answer (score 2):

After you created your user, before you log out of your old user make sure he is in the right groups:

```
sudo adduser --home /home/<new-username> <new-username>

sudo usermod -aG adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare <new-username>
```

Then :

```
mv -v ~/* /home/<new-username>/
chown -R <new-username>:<new-username> /home/<new-username>/*
```

As @Zzzach pointed out in the comment do not use `sudo`on the `chown` command, firtly it shouldn't be needed because if you did the `mv`as well without sudo all files and folders which belong not to you will remain in old folder and should be anywys recreated on the new user. The system is normal not picky with ownership and permissions but some proggramms are.

Comment: One note, do NOT use `sudo` on the final `chown` command. If some items fail to change permission, it is because they belong to root (and they should stay belonging to root). Not many applications or features require root to own a specific folder, but some are picky.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using rsync to stay on the sage side:

`rsync -rlvzu --owner=<new-username> --chmod=a+rwx,g+rwx,o-wx /source/ /destination/`

where

- `-r` for recursive
- `-l` for links
- `-v` for verbose
- `-z` for compression
- `-u`: updates the files instead of overwriting them (saving time)
- `--chmod=a+rwx,g+rwx,o-wx`: updates the permissions